# PHP 5.4.3 configuration with Apache 2.2

Tags: php, apache-2.2, configuration

Recently I downloaded php 5.4.3 , Apache 2.2 and mysql 5.5.24.

How I will configure these things manually in my windows7. I found some tutorials.

In that they are telling need to add these line in apache conf file

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

But in my php 5.4.3 folder I can't found any files named like this. I downloaded it from php.net website.

Is there any manual available for configuring all these things.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Try WAMP: http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: why dont you use wamp stack for this ?

Comment: Latest wamp server php version is 5.3.10.. latest php stable version is 5.4.3. I want to upgrade my php 5.2.2 to latest php stable version.

Comment: For local development, you could use the built-in CLI web server: `php -S localhost:8000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring your web stack manually isn't trivial. I suggest rather installing [WAMPServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), which incorporates Apache, MySQL and PHP in an easy installer. It will correctly configure the file handlers for you as well, so you won't have to worry about manually configuring Apache to serve your PHP files.

The latest version of PHP bundled with WAMP is version 5.3.10, which is more than recent enough to handle pretty much anything you can throw at it. PHP 5.4 is barely a couple of months old; unless you require specific PHP 5.4 functionality, there really isn't any reason not to stick with version 5.3.10.

Full installation instructions for PHP 5.4 with WAMP are beyond the scope of this answer, so I'll provide [a link for instructions](http://www.bluefrog.ca/2012/03/adding-php-5-4-0-final-support-to-wampserver/) instead. Summarised, you install WAMP, then extract PHP 5.4 into the correct PHP directory within WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no php5apache2_2.dll, means that you downloaded PHP nts (non-Thread Safe), you have to download PHP ts (Thread-Safe), this version has the phpXapache2_X.dll files.